# Laravel session - put() return null

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

At first.

I saw this questions:
[Laravel 5 - session put not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708756/laravel-5-session-put-not-working)
[Laravel session key is null after put in session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504907/laravel-session-key-is-null-after-put-in-session)
[laravel session returning null inspite of setting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760900/laravel-session-returning-null-inspite-of-setting-it)
[Laravel 5 - session doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346743/laravel-5-session-doesnt-work)

Trying to modify my code but nothing changed.

Problem:

On `http://localhost:8000/session/set` - trying to save the session (var_dump returning NULL)
On `http://localhost:8000/session/get` - trying to get this session which i saved but it doesn't.

My code in `SessionController.php`:

```
    class SessionController extends Controller{
        public function accessSessionData(Request $request){
            if($request->session()->has('name')){
                    var_dump($request->session()->get('name'));
            }
            else{
                    echo 'No data in the session.';
            }
            }

            public function storeSessionData(Request $request){
                    var_dump($Crequest->session()->put('name','Filip'));
                    echo "Data has been set.";
            }
}
```

My code in `route.php`:

```
Route::get('session/get', 'SessionController@accessSessionData');

Route::get('session/set', 'SessionController@storeSessionData');

Route::get('session/delete', 'SessionController@deleteSessionData');
```

In `session.php` driver set to `file` with standard `storage_path`.

Folder which storage sessions - chmod `755`

Any ideas ?

Comment: ok, nevermind. I just follow this way:
1. In terminal: `composer require illuminate/html`
2. add in config/app.php in providers `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,`
3. in the same file: `'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,`
4. save file
5. restart serv and everything (restarted computer too)

And pull() returning null in var_dump() even if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can to use another approach to store/get data from session with using function `session()`;

Get the session object: `$session = session();`

Put a new value to session: `$session = session(['key' => 'value']);`

Get a value from session: `$value = session('key');`